# Transforming Observables in RxJava and RxScala

Tags: rx-scala

I have an Observable that emits a List of entries as below:

```
val obsList: Observable[List[MyEntry] = Observable.from(getListEntry)

// getListEntry would give me a List[MyEntry]
```

How could I now get the contents piped into another Observable that takes in a MyEntry? I mean, for each entry in the original Observable, I would need to pipe them to another Observable that has a type signature of:

```
Observable[MyEntry]
```

Comment: Which version are you using? `Observable.from(getListEntry)` should return `Observable [MyEntry]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this! I'm using the Monifu library!

So, I would be doing:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOfEntry)
```

Comment: Why not try RxScala? :)

Comment: The Monifu library was already in use on our system landscape, so I had to use it! Does RxScala has the back pressure baked into the library?

Comment: Yes, RxScala is a wrapper of RxJava and RxJava supports back pressure.

Comment: The onNext in Monifu is something like this: def onNext(elem: T): Future[Ack], but the RxScala returns a Unit?